# SQLSTATE 58004, Error "invalid qnc assigment" when using NULL in JSON_OBJECT() with LISTAGG in DB2 LUW

Tags: sql, json, db2, db2-luw

There seems to be an interesting combination of features that lead to an error in Db2 LUW v11.5.0.0. To reproduce, write:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t (a INT);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1), (2);

SELECT '[' || listagg(
  json_object(
    KEY 'a' VALUE a,
    KEY 'b' VALUE b
  ), ','
) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a) || ']'
FROM (
  SELECT a, NULL b
  FROM t
  ORDER BY a
);
```

I'm using `LISTAGG` to work around Db2 LUW's missing `JSON_ARRAYAGG` support.

The error I'm getting is this:

> The SQL statement or command failed because of a database system error. (Reason "invalid qnc assigment".). SQLCODE=-901, SQLSTATE=58004, DRIVER=4.7.85

Quite probably a bug in the parser. There doesn't seem to be anything obviously wrong. How can this be prevented / worked around?

Comment: Always in best shape. I admire the way you implement JOOQ to work on multiple RDBMSes/versions and find non-obvious errors on the way. Keep going :)

Comment: You should never use untyped `NULL` values in Db2. Despite the fact that `CALL ADMIN_CMD('DESCRIBE SELECT 1 a, NULL b FROM sysibm.sysdummy1')` returns `VARCHAR(1)` for `b`, it's only implicit guessing. Db2 should know exact column data type to use the value properly further...

Comment: @MarkBarinstein: Sure it's a risk, and it used to be much worse. These days, Db2 can handle untyped `NULL` values much better. But the workarounds I've documented show that this is just a plain simple bug. There's no valid reason for this error. For example, removing the `ORDER BY` clause in the derived table "fixes it", or the `COALESCE(b, NULLIF(1, 1))` hack, too.

Comment: This does not reproduce on a newer Db2 level (i.e. the container only v11.5.2.0 release)

Comment: @LukasEder Sorry for spamming here, but I think I have an answer for `JSON` null for MySQL: `select j, j is null, j = 'null', j = CAST('null' AS JSON)
FROM (SELECT json_extract('{"x":null}' ,'$.x') AS j) t` **[demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7MeLXoEQT8dJEMe9TTy1TH/0)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a few workarounds which I'd like to document here, in case someone runs into this as well:

**Cast the NULL literal to a specific type**

```sql
SELECT '[' || listagg(
  json_object(
    KEY 'a' VALUE a,
    KEY 'b' VALUE b
  ), ','
) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a) || ']'
FROM (
  SELECT a, CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(1)) b -- Workaround here
  FROM t
  ORDER BY a
);
```

**Cast the value in JSON_OBJECT**

It might not be possible to know the type of `b`, which could also be numeric, instead of a string.

```sql
SELECT '[' || listagg(
  json_object(
    KEY 'a' VALUE a,
    KEY 'b' VALUE CAST(b AS VARCHAR(32672)) -- Workaround here
  ), ','
) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a) || ']'
FROM (
  SELECT a, NULL b
  FROM t
  ORDER BY a
);
```

**Remove the ORDER BY clause, which is not needed in this case (it could be if there was a `FETCH FIRST` clause)**

```sql
SELECT '[' || listagg(
  json_object(
    KEY 'a' VALUE a,
    KEY 'b' VALUE b
  ), ','
) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a) || ']'
FROM (
  SELECT a, NULL b
  FROM t
  -- Workaround here
);
```

**Adding an expression that "obfuscates" the NULL value**

```sql
SELECT '[' || listagg(
  json_object(
    KEY 'a' VALUE a,
    KEY 'b' VALUE COALESCE(b, NULLIF(1, 1)) -- Workaround here
  ), ','
) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY a) || ']'
FROM (
  SELECT a, NULL b
  FROM t
  ORDER BY a
);
```

All of these producing the desired

```
1                                  |
-----------------------------------|
[{"a":1,"b":null},{"a":2,"b":null}]|
```